# Ruby - unknown regexp options - akt

Tags: ruby

I am fairly new to Ruby. I am trying to execute a simple ruby command from a ruby file from irb.

I have created a file `beginend.rb` with only a single statement `puts "Hello World"`. When I tried to execute the script (`irb(main):073:0> /home/sanket/codebase/ruby-excercise/beginend.rb`) from irb, I get following error:

```
irb(main):073:0> /home/sanket/codebase/ruby-excercise/beginend.rb 
SyntaxError: (irb):73: unknown regexp options - akt
    from /home/sanket/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
```

I am using ruby 1.9.3 which was installed using rvm.

Can someone please tell me what this error message means? I tried to look online but cannot find anything.

I also tried putting `#!/usr/bin/ruby`, but with no luck.

Comment: `ruby /home/sanket/codebase/ruby-excercise/beginend.rb`

Comment: `irb> exec '/home/sanket/codebase/ruby-excercise/beginend.rb'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you execute ruby files from within ruby. Try this:

```
irb(main):001:0> load '/home/sanket/codebase/ruby-excercise/beginend.rb'
```

Answer (score 2):

You execute the script from your bash:

```
$ ruby beginend.rb
```

If you want to execute it from IRB for some reason see Sergio's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below in your `irb` session.

```
 require '/home/sanket/codebase/ruby-excercise/beginend.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the code below, replace the specific_folder_name with the folder beginend.rb is at; in your case seems like it's

```
$ ruby <specific_folder_name>/beginend.rb
```